# how to get mean of values in col c, in bins based on col b, in a group defined in col a

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate, binning

I have a pandas dataframe with tens of thousands of rows and about 15 columns, five of which are represented below. The data associated with each RELATEID location are points that have a POINT_TOP value with a potential range of 96 up to 495 (varies per location) in increments of 1, and each point has an associated kclass of 1, 2, or 3. What I need to do is group the data by RELATEID, then bin the POINT_TOP data for each RELATEID in uniform increments of 10 starting at 96-105 then 106-115, etc... and get the average value of kclass for each of those groups of 10. I then want to write out a new dataframe that has RELATEID, LAYER_TOP, and kclass_avg columns along with the x and y columns where the values stay the same for each unique RELATEID.

| RELATEID | POINT_TOP | x | y | kclass |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20202 | 102 | 331312 | 5031942 | 1 |
| 20852 | 102 | 331295 | 5031955 | 3 |
| 20202 | 103 | 331312 | 5031942 | 1 |
| 20852 | 103 | 331295 | 5031955 | 3 |
| 20202 | 104 | 331312 | 5031942 | 1 |
| 20852 | 104 | 331295 | 5031955 | 3 |
| 20202 | 105 | 331312 | 5031942 | 1 |
| 20852 | 105 | 331295 | 5031955 | 3 |
| 20202 | 106 | 331312 | 5031942 | 1 |
| 20852 | 106 | 331295 | 5031955 | 3 |
| 20202 | 107 | 331312 | 5031942 | 2 |
| 20852 | 107 | 331295 | 5031955 | 2 |
| 20202 | 108 | 331312 | 5031942 | 3 |
| 20852 | 108 | 331295 | 5031955 | 2 |
| 20202 | 109 | 331312 | 5031942 | 3 |
| 20852 | 109 | 331295 | 5031955 | 1 |
| 20202 | 110 | 331312 | 5031942 | 3 |
| 20852 | 110 | 331295 | 5031955 | 1 |
| 20202 | 111 | 331312 | 5031942 | 3 |
| 20852 | 111 | 331295 | 5031955 | 1 |
| 20202 | 112 | 331312 | 5031942 | 3 |
| 20852 | 112 | 331295 | 5031955 | 1 |
| 20202 | 113 | 331312 | 5031942 | 3 |
| 20852 | 113 | 331295 | 5031955 | 1 |

I am a relative novice and have tried .cut with .groupby and .agg in various combinations and I get syntax errors or it starts running and never stops. Does this need to be a multistep operation? I think I could figure it out if I wrote out each RELATEID as its own dataframe, took a mean of kclass within the POINT_TOP bins (so only two levels of complication instead of three), then concatenated the results all back together, but was hoping someone might know a simpler way. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Sorry for being confusing. Below is what I am trying to get to for output using the data from above. Each RELATEID location would have a row for each of the bins that contains data and the LAYER_TOP would would be either the top of the range (e.g. 115) or the whole range of the bin (e.g. 115-106) and the layer_kclass would be the average of the kclass values in that bin.

| RELATEID | LAYER_TOP | x | y | layer_kclass |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20202 | 115 | 331312 | 5031942 | 2.625 |
| 20202 | 105 | 331312 | 5031942 | 1 |
| 20852 | 115 | 331295 | 5031955 | 1.5 |
| 20852 | 105 | 331295 | 5031955 | 3 |

If it helps to visualize, these are well logs. Each unique RELATEID represents a single well. The POINT_TOP breaks the elevation within the well into 1-meter increments and the kclass is a geology identifier for that 1-meter. I am trying to average the kclass into consistent 10-meter intervals for each well instead of 1-meter.

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: TL;DR: Just show what you have and how is the output you expect. Regards

Comment: Can you provide your desired output for the provided input?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tracked your question until a point, and here is the code to reach that point:

```
_, bins = pd.cut(range(96, 495), 40, retbins=True)
data.groupby('RELATEID').agg({'POINT_TOP': lambda x: list(pd.cut(x, bins = bins)), 'kclass': 'mean'})
```

Output

```
    POINT_TOP   kclass
RELATEID        
20202   [(95.602, 105.95], (95.602, 105.95], (95.602, ...   2.0
20852   [(95.602, 105.95], (95.602, 105.95]]    2.0
415704  [(484.05, 494.0]]   2.0
646012  [(484.05, 494.0], (484.05, 494.0]]  2.0
```

Comment: This was close, but not exactly what I needed. I ended up getting it to work by using groupby to make groups by 'RELATEID', then did a pd.cut to separate the rows into the different layers while creating a new column with the layer label in it. I could then groupby the layer labels and calculate the 'kclass' mean. The I could write out new dataframes for each 'RELATEID'  that had one row per layer, followed by concatenating all of the new data back into a single dataframe.
I am sure that there is likely a single line that could stack everything I did, but that is beyond my knowledge for now.